# CKEditor change default format

Tags: styles, ckeditor, default

i try to change the default selected format in ckeditor
i added it in the styles.js

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('mystyles', [

            {name: 'My styly style', element: 'p', styles: {'color': 'blue'}},
        ]);
```

and when my instance of ck loads i would lije to select by default the format when i click in the editor to change the texte .

Anyone has the answer

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line in your config.js:

```
config.format_p = { element: 'p', attributes: { 'class': 'color_blue' } };
```

** Do not forget to add (in your css)

```
 .color_blue{
   color:blue;
 }
```